# supabase auth.uid() = user_id equals false

Tags: postgresql, authentication, supabase

I have a very strange problem that is driving we up the walls.
I am creating the following table

```
CREATE TABLE articles(
  id BIGINT generated by default as IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id uuid references auth.users NOT NULL,
  title TEXT,
  CONTENT TEXT,
  user_email TEXT,
  inserted_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT timezone('utc'::TEXT,NOW()) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE articles ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE policy "users can create articles" ON articles for
INSERT WITH CHECK(auth.uid() = user_id);

CREATE policy "users can update their own articles" ON articles for
UPDATE USING (auth.uid() = user_id);

CREATE policy "users can delete their own articles" ON articles for
DELETE USING (auth.uid() = user_id);

CREATE policy "users can read their own articles" ON articles for
SELECT USING (auth.uid() = user_id);
```

I can add data to it through my front-end with:

```
            const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.from("articles").insert(
                [{
                    title: title,
                    content: content,
                    user_email: user?.email?.toLowerCase(),
                    user_id: user?.id,
                }]
            ).single()
```

and that works. I can verify on supabase that the row has indeed been added.

[image: Entry got added]

However, I can't access my data through the front-end since the expression:
auth.uid() = user_id seems to evaluate to false even though it is the same. If I disable Row level security or write TRUE instead everything works as intended.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is very odd. To double check, could you add the frontend code you are using to retrieve the data and also a screenshot of the RLS policy for select in your Supabase dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself, and found an answer from Jon Meyers of the Supabase team.  Headers need to be added to your request manually.

```
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export default async function Page() {
  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/test", {
    headers: headers(),
  });

  return ...
}
```

https://jonmeyers.io/blog/forwarding-cookies-from-server-components-to-route-handlers-with-next-js-app-router

> The problem is that the cookie — an auth token, for example — is set between our browser and the server. When our browser requests a Server Component route, it sends the cookies along with the request:

> Browser → Server Component

> If the Server Component makes a fetch call to a Route Handler, it doesn’t know to attach the original request’s headers and cookies.

> Browser → Server Component → Route Handler

> If we want them to be available in the Route Handler, we need to manually attach them to the fetch request from the Server Component.